# "crying remember" or "remember crying"? -- "One day, you will ______ my words!"

Tags: word-order, adjuncts

Let say that someone is not listening to your advise which is for his/her benefit and making a big mistake.

So can he say:

> One day, you will **crying remember** my words!

Or

> One day, you will **remember crying** my words!

Comment: We  say: "Don't come boohooing to me."

Comment: "One day you will cry remembering my words."

Answer (score 1):

In the first rendering, "crying remember" is bad syntax.  The placement of "crying" next to the verb "remember" cries out for an adverb.  But "crying" applies to the person, not the remembering.  That is:

[crying person] remembering

The second is definitely wrong because the second person did not "cry" the first person's words!  (in "remember crying my words", *remember* is the verb, and *crying my words* is the direct object.)

In my opinion, the most concise, grammatically correct and accurate way to phrase this thought would be:

- One day you will cry, remembering my words.

This means that he will cry and remember at the same time.

If you wish to stress that the remembering will trigger the crying, say

- One day you will remember my words and cry.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can throw in an explanation, no extra cost.

Answer (score 0):

The word that should precede **remember** is an adverb.

How will you remember my words? - **[cryingly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cryingly)**

> One day you will **cryingly** remember my words!

But I would say it this way, a more common way -

> One day you will cry and remember my words!

Comment: Yes, remember and cry are two actions, but I mean  one action only and second one as a quality of the action.

Comment: Since you have the object "my words" after "remember", you can't have an adverb there, you need to keep them together for grammar's sake.  You can put "cryingly" after "my words", but it changes the meaning, suggesting that the act of remembering is what will make the person cry, which is not what you intend to say.  I recommend "One day, wiping away tears you will remember my words."

Comment: @VictorBazarov I am not a native speaker. But I have noticed, very few though, that *cryingly + verb + object* form is there. But I found more examples of *cryingly* modifying an adjective than *crying* modifying a verb. So I just want to know what is correct? Or are both of them correct?

Comment: It is quite possible that more than one order of words is fine (English is not so strict as is sometimes portrayed) and gives the same meaning.  I can't say I've done enough research to authoritatively state one way or the other about the correctness of the use of "cryingly".  As a matter of fact, as I type the word here, it is marked with a wavy red line to indicate that Internet Explorer's dictionary doesn't have it, from which I conclude that it's not a common word...

Comment: @victor yes it's not that common. And so I in my answer wrote "the more common way..." etc. I have provided the link also in my answer that will take you to Wiktionary where it defines the word. Moreover OED and Collins have entry for that word :-)

Comment: I don't doubt the word, I am sure that I've encountered it previously myself, and, honestly, no need suggesting to me to look it up, seriously, really.  You're asking whether both are correct, and I say, yes, likely.  You've done more research, so **you** are now an authority between us two.

Comment: @VictorBazarov :-) not like that. Yes I have done some search, that's all. You are native speaker, you have more knowledge as to what sounds better and what not, and all these things. And I myself found very little example sentences where this word modifies a verb.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, I am not a native speaker of English.  Just an enthusiast who likes to think he's paying attention.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Not a problem :-) As far as learning is concerned, we can learn from anyone, be it a native speaker or a nonnative speaker :-)